# ini4j only works from the libs directory, not maven

Tags: android, aide-ide, ini4j

I'm trying to use ini4j in an Android app, compiled in the AIDE IDE. When I put ini4j-0.5.4.jar in the libs folder in my app, it works. However, when I include ini4j with the line `compile 'org.ini4j:ini4j:0.5.4'` in my build.gradle, I get the error `bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004`. I've checked the jar file in the Maven directory, and it is identical to the one in my libs folder. Both have the SHA1 `4a3ee4146a90c619b20977d65951825f5675b560`. I have absolutely no clue what could be causing this.

EDIT: For some reason, it seems to have xerces as a dependency, which is the library known to have these issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apache (http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/install.html) xerces.jar is now deprecated and renamed to xercesImpl.jar, so you have to stick to the old JAR.

> xerces.jar is no longer available in the main distribution. You can still download this jar from deprecated distribution. xerces.jar is a Jar file that contains all the parser class files (i.e., it contains the intersection of the contents of xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar).

To be clearer, the technical details are:

1. The old xerces.jar you have in your libs folder is working, because of the internal folder structure.
2. The new xerces from the repository has a different folder structure and some weird UTF encoded bytes AIDE is not understanding.

Comment: I'm not using Xerces, or at least not trying to. I mean ini4j doesn't work unless I include the ini4j jar, because somewhere along the dependency tree ini4j requires it (it doesn't show on the dependency tree on their site, so it's at least a dependency of a dependency of a dependency, but I'm not sure what for).